# Action Script 3.0 move movieclip from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object, multiple-instances

I have a "Charselection" and "Charname" (linked with a movieclip - extended to charselection) and "Charname2"(linked with another movieclip - extended to charselection)
I have some mouse events and stuff, but I want to know, how to make the code, to know which
one clicked. I tried `var charname1 = this.name` and then trace it, and it worked, but I want to select it as object, not to know the name.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could use the mouseEvent object that is sent to your mouse listener, and get the event target.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way:

Suppose you have a `stage` variable which link to the display object, the latter being the base container for the "Charname" and "Charname2", you can assign a mouse event listener to the base container in the following way:

```
var stage:DisplayObject = new DisplayObject();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, select);
```

...then use `event.target` to get the object being triggered:

```java
function select(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(e.target);
}
```